# Error executing MSCK REPAIR TABLE on external Hive table (Hive 2.3.6)

Tags: hive, spark-thriftserver

I have created an external Hive table based on a partitioned Parquet file in S3 using a statement similar to this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.person
(
    first_name STRING,
    last_name STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (age INT)
STORED AS parquet
LOCATION 's3a://default/person.parquet'"
```

The table is created and running **DESCRIBE TABLE default.person** shows:

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
|         col_name         | data_type  | comment  |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
| first_name               | string     | NULL     |
| last_name                | string     | NULL     |
| # Partition Information  |            |          |
| # col_name               | data_type  | comment  |
| age                      | int        | NULL     |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
```

However when I query the table with Beeline it returns zero records. I think I need to refresh the partition info in the Hive Metastore.

So I run **MSCK REPAIR TABLE default.person** but it fails with this error:

```
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table) (state=,code=0)
```

Am I on the right path, and why might this error be occurring ?

Hive version is 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent command on Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR)'s version of Hive is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

See [Recover Partitions manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) for more details.

Comment: I have tried that, get the same error -> ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS;
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table) (state=,code=0).

Not running in EMR though, system in on-prem